# Acumatica is not showing table colums in DAC Generator

Tags: acumatica

i have a situation where i created a new Table in Acumatica DB and i use de DAC Generator to create the class, i've chose the table and it shows no columns of the table, i've tried with other DB, another Acumatica Framework and it does keep showing no colums... any help ?

[image: DB TABLE QUERY] [image: DAC GENERATOR SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Are you able to make the Visual Studio extension generate an error message? It might be difficult to debug without an error message. Also the VS templates are an area that tends to lag behind a bit. That's why I recommended to use the customization project editor in web browser in my answer.

Comment: The extension does not generate any error. I will try the Customization you mentioned

Comment: There might be something in one of the Output Windows accessible from Debug-Windows menu. Would still recommend the customization project editor as it is regularly updated.

Comment: I've tried he Customization Project Editor and when i click on "OK" in the Add => Code it says "Unknown SqlDbType"

Comment: That could be the error message. Check column types used in the database table and try to locate one which isn't in the other tables. Date type is suspicious, not sure it's mapped in the DAC so changing it to DateTime would help. Identity should work but isn't very common. The other types looks good at first glance.

Comment: That was the problem!! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating the DAC using the Customization Project Editor instead.

Procedure:

```
1. Create new table in database
2. Reset the website (IISReset or go to page Apply Updates and use Restart Application)
3. Create a new customization project
4. Navigate to code section and insert a new code document
5. Use wizard to generate the DAC from the database table
```

[image]

Comment: When I do this - I get "Unknown SqlDbType" 

I have recycled the application pools, restarted IIS, restarted the application, verified that the table (in this case it is a view) exists in the DB

Comment: It sounds like the table has at least one column data type which is not compatible with Acumatica. Review if the column data types are all mapped in Acumatica here: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/09/database-mapped-vs-virtual-fields.html

Comment: Also check my comment in the question above, it's the same error as yours.